# Почему появляется ошибка "undefined reference to" при линковке кода на другой системе?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, ld

Есть код, который линкуется и компилируется везде нормально, но на моей системе линкуется с ошибками.
Все ошибки начинаются с `undefined reference to` и связаны с компонентами библиотеки `string.h`.
Если закомментировать все участки с использованием `string.h`, то код заработает.
Вот код:

```
#include "keyboard_map.h"
#include <string.h>


extern unsigned char keyboard_map[128];
void keyboard_handler(void);
char read_port(unsigned short port);
void write_port(unsigned short port, unsigned char data);
void load_idt(unsigned long *idt_ptr);
char *name = "blablabla >";
char command[80];
int kernel = 0;
char fillkey = '.';
int fillcolor = 0xf7;
int on = 1;

unsigned int cur = 0;
char *video = (char*)0xb8000;

struct IDT_entry {
    short int offset_lowerbits;
    short int selector;
    char zero;
    char type_attr;
    short int offset_higherbits;
};

struct IDT_entry IDT[256];

void idt_init(void) {
    long keyboard_address;
    long idt_address;
    long idt_ptr[2];

    keyboard_address = (unsigned long)keyboard_handler;
    IDT[0x21].offset_lowerbits = keyboard_address & 0xffff;
    IDT[0x21].selector = 0x08;
    IDT[0x21].type_attr = 0x8e;
    IDT[0x21].offset_higherbits = (keyboard_address & 0xffff0000) >> 16;

    write_port(0x20 , 0x11);
    write_port(0xA0 , 0x11);
    write_port(0x21 , 0x20);
    write_port(0xA1 , 0x28);
    write_port(0x21 , 0x00);
    write_port(0xA1 , 0x00);
    write_port(0x21 , 0x01);
    write_port(0xA1 , 0x01);
    write_port(0x21 , 0xff);
    write_port(0xA1 , 0xff);

    idt_address = (unsigned long)IDT ;
    idt_ptr[0] = (sizeof (struct IDT_entry) * 256) + ((idt_address & 0xffff) << 16);
    idt_ptr[1] = idt_address >> 16 ;

    load_idt(idt_ptr);
}

void kb_init(void) {
    write_port(0x21 , 0xFD);
}

void kprint(const char *str) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        video[cur++] = str[i++];
        video[cur++] = 0xf0;
    }
}

void clear_screen() {
    int i = 0;
    cur = 0;
    while (i < 4000) {
        video[i++] = fillkey;
        video[i++] = fillcolor;
    }
    kprint(name);
}

void kprint_newline(const char *str) {
    cur = cur + (160 - cur % (160));
    if (cur > 3840) clear_screen();
    else if (strcmp(command, "help") == 0) {
        kprint("!!!");
    } else if (strcmp(command, "clear") == 0) {
        clear_screen();
    } else if (strcmp(command, "shutdown") == 0) {
        on = -100;
    } else {
        if (str) kprint(str);
    }
        memset(command,0,80);
}

void keyboard_handler_main() {
    unsigned char status;
    char keycode;

    write_port(0x20, 0x20);

    status = read_port(0x64);
    if (status & 0x01) {
        keycode = read_port(0x60);
        if (keycode < 0) return;
        if (keycode == 28) {
            kprint_newline(name);
        } else if (keycode == 14) {
            if (strlen(command) > 0) {
            cur-= 2;
            kprint(".");
            command[strlen(command) - 1] = 0;
            cur-= 2;
            }
            } else {
        int key = keyboard_map[(unsigned char) keycode];
        command[strlen(command)] = key;
        video[cur++] = key;
        video[cur++] = 0xf0;
    }
    }
}

void main() {
    clear_screen();
    idt_init();
    kb_init();
    while(1) {
    if (on == -100) break;  
    };
}
```

вот лог `ld` с ошибками:

```
bin/kc.o: In function `kprint_newline':
kernel.c:(.text+0x251): undefined reference to `strcmp'
kernel.c:(.text+0x27c): undefined reference to `strcmp'
kernel.c:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `strcmp'
kernel.c:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `memset'
bin/kc.o: In function `keyboard_handler_main':
kernel.c:(.text+0x387): undefined reference to `strlen'
kernel.c:(.text+0x3c4): undefined reference to `strlen'
```

Версия gcc: 5.4.0
Версия ld: 2.26.1
Стоит Ubuntu 16.04
Комманды компиляции и линковки:
gcc -fno-stack-protector -m32 -c kernel.c -o bin/kc.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o bin/kernel bin/kasm.o bin/kc.o

Comment: Как выглядят команды компиляции и линковки?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. теперь команды компиляции и линковки там.

Comment: Ну так по-видимому подменненый через `-T link.ld` linker script и оставил вас без стандартной библиотеки. Проект по ссылке не пользуется стандартными библиотечными функциями - там нет ни `memset`, ни `strcmp`, ни `strlen`. С чего вы взяли, что вы сможете ими пользоваться?

Comment: И что означает ваше "линкуется и компилируется везде нормально"? Где именно эта ваша версия "линкуется и компилируется нормально"?

Comment: Без `-T link.ld` тоже не работает.

Comment: Я пробовал этот код на двух других системах.

Comment: Что такое "тоже не работает"? Те же ошибки? И что означает ваша фраза "форк этого проекта, там те же ошибки." Каким образом в проекте по ссылке могут быть "те же ошибки", если там вообще нет использования таких функций?

Comment: Похоже, я попутал логи. Действительно, эти ошибки не имеют отношения к изначальному коду, с которого делался форк.

Comment: @Ant, ну очевидно же, что пытаются собрать некое подобие игрушечного приложения в формате типа *ядро ОС*. Понятно, что все функции надо  расписывать самому (можно подсмотреть, как это сделано к примеру в Linux в *arch/x86/boot* или другой архитектуры).

Answer (score 1):

В языке С нет никакой "библиотеки `string.h`". `string.h` - это *заголовочный файл* с объявлениями функций из *Стандартной Библиотеки Языка С*. В вашем случае стандартная библиотека просто умышленно не подключена.